# on component re rendering in react does the objects defined inside the component also created new as functions do

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

on component re rendering in react does the objects defined inside the component also created new as functions do , if yes then if we are passing it as props then the particular child component would also be called , so it is wise to use useMemo hook , for example
const selected = useMemo(() => selectedColumn, [selectedColumn]);

I am confused for the same

Comment: Hello @ayanaggarwal, welcome to StackOverflow. I didn't understand your question. 
Feel free to use Google Translator or similar service if english is not your native language. Also, you can get more answers here if you include [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your question.

Comment: I mean to say that can useMemo hook be used to avoid unnecessary re rendering of the component or its just work to bypass expensive calculations

Comment: @PawelKam please let me know whether usecallbacks or usememo can prevent unnecessary re rendering of the component ?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what kind of value it is. Some kinds of value will always give you a new reference when the code is run again (objects, arrays, functions, etc.), while others will always give you the same reference (booleans, numbers, strings, etc.)

```
{} === {}               // false
[] === []               // false
(() => 3) === (() => 3) // false

false === false         // true
42 === 42               // true
"hello" === "hello"     // true
```

In the first case you should use `useMemo`, or `useCallback` for functions, or just avoid passing such values to the children if possible.

In the second case there is no point in using `useCallback` at all, because the new value is already equal to the old value.

**Edit:**
To clarify a bit more, when a component rerenders then all of its children, grandchildren, etc. rerender as well. This has nothing to do with props or `useMemo`. You can prevent it by using `React.memo` or by moving your state down to avoid rerendering components high up in the tree. See also https://overreacted.io/before-you-memo/

Answer (score -1):

Yes. When a component re-renders, any objects or variables inside the components will be recreated, and will cause the child component to re-render if these objects/variables were passed as props.

Using useMemo hook will let you "memoize" the object/variable and it will prevent unnecessary re-renders.

In the example you have given above, child component will not rerender unless selectedColumn has changed.

Please read docs below for more details.
https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useMemo#skipping-re-rendering-of-components

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).